# How to use neural networks and the synaptic library to make a project pricing estimator

Tags: javascript, neural-network

As someone new to machine learning I have some basic questions.

So I have small dataset of projects with a whole bunch of properties that may or may not affect the price of a product, as well as the prices of each project.

How should I set up [synaptic](http://synaptic.juancazala.com) to create a pricing engine that can estimate prices of new projects based on some or all of these properties?  Specifically what kind of neural networks should I configure with the library.

For instance - in the demo of synaptic, I see it using a perceptron architecture - what would be appropriate for my case and what should I set up as a structure to experiment with.

Answer (score 1):

> I have small dataset of projects

Then you should not use neural networks. Especially in this scenario, where there are a lot of variables. Your network will just remember some of the test cases and won't find a real ongoing pattern.

If you manage to get your hands on a **large** dataset, then the [perceptron architecture](https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/wiki/Architect#perceptron) type is a good option. You have to experiment what layer amount and what neuron amount works best at the testcases.

Also know that with [Synaptic](https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/) you have to scale your input between `0` and `1`. If a certain property is not active on a project, use input `0`. The output (price) should also be scaled between 0 and 1. Just divide your price by 100000 for example (depending on previous costs).

Create the perceptron with `var network = new Architect.Perceptron(n_variables, hiddenlayersizes, output_size)` then use the [trainer](https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/wiki/Trainer) to train your testcases.